# localizing text before settext

Tags: java, android

Is there any Java and Android API which I can invoke and pass a String object and get back the localized text corresponding to the current locale set by the user in his android device.

Here I am trying to avoid manually translating text and creating multiple raw-xxx or values-xxx folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do automated translation then it's rather bad idea. Automated translation is usually crappy. `values-xxx` is exactly for that so if you insist to have automated translation, use whatever tool you want (or site like crowdin.net etc and their automated translation) and create assets for your `values-xx` folder and then you done.

Comment: Hi Marcin, could you pls. explain how can I provide support for Brazil where Portuguese is main language but it is not the same Portuguese as spoken in Portugal.

Comment: You put the one for Brasil in `values-br-rBR` and for Portugal in `value-br-rPT`

Answer (score 0):

With Google Translate, you can dynamically translate text between thousands of language pairs.
**The Google Translate API** lets websites and programs integrate with Google Translate programmatically. Get started here:

https://developers.google.com/translate/

Ok so if you are looking for a free one then Bing seems to offer a free translation API. Here you go:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Comment: @Sandeep You didn't mention that you need a free one ;-)

Comment: @Sandeep Updated the answer with a free API option. It seems Bing is offering it for free. Give it a try!